# Moving cell data to respective row based on numbers in another column

Tags: excel

I have a list of parts that have a part code. I need to align columns B-E to match the list of numbers in column A, leaving blanks where the data has moved down. The number in column B should match the number in column A.

A simple sort will not do because ColumnB,D,E has fewer entries than ColumnA and some numbers in ColumnB are not in ColumnA.

| A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| '005023 | 5025 | oil-filler-level-plug-genuine-005025 | GENUINE PIAGGIO, OIL FILLER PLUG. | 1.5 |
| '005024 | 5027 | rear-hub-cone-shim-lambretta-005027 | LAMBRETTA REAR HUB CONE SHIM. | 1.25 |
| '005025 | 5031 | piston-s2-s3-524mm-125cc-gol-005031 | ITALIAN MADE BY GOL | 46.5 |
| '005027 | 5032 | exhaust-simonini-px-125-black-005032 |  | 135 |
| '005029 | 5036 | floor-runner-kit-vespa-px-125-200-005036 | GOOD QUALITY, ITALIAN MADE, COMLETE FLOOR RUNNER KIT | 25 |
| '005031 | 5037 | rear-light-grey-top-for-vespa-rally-005037 |  | 5 |
| '005032 | 5038 | front-hub-back-plate-chrome-005038 | Suitable for all Lambretta S1 S2 S3 models | 45 |
| '005033 | 5041 | clutch-plates-surflex-cosa-vespa-px-005041 | TOP QUALITY ITALIAN COSA CLUTCH PLATES MADE BY SURFLEX. | 16 |
| '005036 | 5044 | points-ducati-style-lambretta-005044 | TOP QUALITY,CONTACT BREAKER POINT FOR LAMBRETTA | 10 |
| '005037 | 5045 | condensor-ducati-dansi-li-sx-tv-gp-005045 | DUCATI TYPE CONDENSOR FOR MOST LAMBRETTAS. | 9 |
| '005038 | 5047 | panel-handle-lock-mechanisms-s1-s2-005047 | TOP QUALITY, LAMBRETTA SERIES 1 & 2 SIDE PANEL HANDLE MECHANISM KIT. | 41 |
| '005040 | 5049 | fork-push-rods-pistons-s1-2-3-005049 | TOP QUALITY LAMBRETTA FORK PUSH ROD PISTON SET. | 12 |
| '005041 | 5050 | fuel-tank-vespa-gs-160-180ss-rally-005050 |  | 100 |
| '005044 | 5051 | wheel-rim-chrome-10-inch-vespa-005051 | TOP QUALITY, CHROMED WHEEL RIMS ( 1 X WHEEL ) | 38 |
| '005045 | 5052 | carb-box-top-carbon-look-pe-px-efl-005052 | VBB SPRINT GT PX | 22 |
| '005047 | 5054 | input-shaft-needle-rollers-px-21-005054 | ITALIAN MADE SET OF 23 INPUT SHAFT NEEDLE ROLLER BEARINGS | 5 |
| '005049 | 5055 | air-hose-clips-19mm-series-2-carb-005055 | LAMBRETTA SERIES1 AND 2 AIR HOSE CLIPS FOR STANDARD | 5 |
| '005050 | 5056 | air-hose-vespa-vna-005056 |  | 6.5 |

Comment: I've removed the bolded section; and removed newlines from the sample data to make it easier to paste into Excel. Please confirm that the question still represents what you were asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a reference from the VBA editor (**Tools** -> **References...**) to **Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects**; choose the latest version, usually 6.1

Then you could write VBA code like the following:

```vba
Const filepath As String = "C:\path\to\excel\file.xlsx"
Const sheetname As String = "Sheet1"

Dim connectionString As String
connectionString = _
    "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
    "Data Source=""" & filepath & """;" & _
    "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=No"""

    ' If your data is in a macro-enabled file (.xlsm), the previous line should
    ' look like this:
    ' "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Macro;HDR=No"""

Dim sql As String
sql = _
    "SELECT F1, F2, F3, F4, F5 " & _
    "FROM (" & _
        "SELECT F1, CInt(Mid(F1, 2)) AS F1_1 " & _
        "FROM [Sheet1$]" & _
    ") AS t1 " & _
    "LEFT JOIN (" & _
        "SELECT F2, F3, F4, F5 FROM [Sheet1$]" & _
    ") AS t2 ON t1.F1_1 = t2.F2"

Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
rs.Open sql, connectionString

Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset(rs)
```

This opens an ADODB Recordset object, using an SQL statement to shape the data.

Since the first column is textual (every cell starts with `'`), we have to remove the initial `'` (using `Mid`) and convert the rest to a number (`CInt`).

Then, we join the first column against the other columns using the converted number; leaving blank cells for the other columns where the first column isn't matched.

Finally, we paste the data (`CopyFromRecordset`) starting from cell `A1` on `Sheet2`.